# Is it possible to install without the Internet?

Tags: 11.10, installation, internet-connection

I have started installing Ubuntu 11.10 on a computer without an internet connection.
Installation has stopped during configuring target system.
The computer seems to be trying to use the Internet to grab updates & software.
How do I get it to continue to install?

Comment: thats strange ... it should not do this

Comment: Ubuntu will install without the internet fine, At what point is your install stopping?

Comment: you might checked the option for install updates during installation,if yes just skip it

Answer (score 2):

If the installer stops during system configuration, you may have encountered a bug, which you can report on http://launchpad.net

I would suggest trying to run the installation again, because it should not pause because of no internet. However, if you continue to encounter this on that hardware, you most likely have a bug with that specific hardware.

You could try using the alternate installer (text based installer).

Answer (score 0):

You can install with out internet but you best can disconnect any network cable and do disable wifi

Bas

Comment: You can also download the dvd image it contains alot more packages some times beter support voor drivers etc etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure **installing is fine**, just **not downloading**, since installing uses a pre-downloaded package.

Answer (score 0):

I've had an experience where the computer just rebooted during the installation of Ubuntu 11.10. I just tried the installation again and it worked fine. You could try reinstalling.